# SQL UPDATE does not work?

Tags: php, mysqli

When I send an email through PHP I want it to update a database saying it has sent the message. But the code below is what I can find online that should work but it does not and I definitely have a connection to the database.

```
$sql = "UPDATE Mail SET Sent='1' WHERE key='$key'";
```

And I get no errors and everything else on the page runs right. Any help?

Comment: You should include solutions you've tried in your question. Did you check /var/log/httpd/*.log? Did you output diagnostic messages?  Did you try running the SQL from a command line tool? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is Sent a bool? If so, try setting to 1 w/o the single quote. Can you run the sql as you have it when putting a valid value in for $key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because "key" is a reserved word in MySQL. There are some others which you find [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, 'key' is a keyword, maybe you can：

```
$sql = "UPDATE Mail SET Sent='1' WHERE `key`='$key'";
```

Comment: KEY is indeed a reserved term.. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html   @Derbyshire10   Suggest renaming your `key` column in your database to something like 'keyid'